# Printing out a 2d array in java... this creates an error

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class ArrayLoops {

    public static int [][] array; //initialize array 

    public static void main (String [] args){

        array = new int[4][4]; //set the amount of data values in array 
        //starts from 0 
        array[0][0] = 9; 
        array[1][3]= 2; 
        array[2][1]= 3; 
        array[3][3] = 5;
        array [3][0] = 1; 
        // ends at 4 because (0,1,2,3) = 4; 

        for (int i= 0; i<array.length; i++) //.length gets # of datas in array
        {
            System.out.println (); 

            for (int j =0; j< array[i].length; i++){    
            System.out.println (array[i][j]); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the console msg is 
9
0
0
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at ArrayLoops.main(ArrayLoops.java:21)

Comment: replace i++ with j++ second loop

Comment: Flagged for deletion - this is a simple typing mistake and unlikely to be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 4):

You are accidentally incrementing `i` in the `j` `for` loop.  This can cause `i` to be incremented out of bounds when it's already `3` and the `j` `for` loop increments it.  Change

```
for (int j =0; j< array[i].length; i++){
```

to

```
for (int j =0; j< array[i].length; j++){
```

Answer (score 1):

In the inner for loop you increment i instead of j

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what the problem is:

In the second for loop you are incrementing j when you should be incrementing i.

```
for (int i= 0; i<array.length; i++) //.length gets # of datas in array
    {
        System.out.println (); 

        for (int j =0; j< array[i].length; j++){ 
            // change such that j is incremented for each iteration
            System.out.println (array[i][j]); 
        }
    }
```

That should work.